# Syntax error passing SQL result to PostgreSQL function accepting array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I tried to pass the result of a SQL query to a function, but I got a syntax error.

```
contacts=> SELECT count(*) FROM update_name(contact_ids := select array(select id from contact where name is NULL));
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: SELECT count(*) FROM update_name(contact_ids := select array...
```

The subselect returns BIGINTs, and the function accepts an array of BIGINTs. I verified that running the subselect and turning the result into an array of BIGINTs works.

Switching to [positional notation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html) did not make a difference. Using an [Array constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) did not change anything, either.

Following an intuition, I wrapped the argument in parens:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM update_name(contact_ids := (select array(select id from contact where name is NULL)));
```

And **that worked**. I don't get why. The [docs on expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-FUNCTION-CALLS) state that arguments in a function call are expressions. Function calls and Array constructors are expressions, so at least using the Array constructor should have worked.

Why do I need the parens? Where does the necessity come from, i.e. how could I have known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression form you are using is called a [Scalar Subquery](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES). The manual says:

> A scalar subquery is an ordinary SELECT query **in parentheses** that
>   returns exactly one row with one column ... The SELECT query is executed and
>   the single returned value is used in the surrounding value expression.

Your subquery returns a single value (which happens to be an array, prepared from the result of another subquery).

As a basic rule of thumb, subqueries are always in parenthesis.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. I usually wrap subselects in parens, but I did not know where the requirement comes from. Scalar subquery explains it. Thank you!